# How can I select ID in Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the unordered list;

```
<ul id="names">
  <li id="john"><div>data from database</div></li>
  <li id="peter"><div>data from database</div></li>
  <li id="mathhewm"><div>data from database</div></li>
  <li id="philip"><div>data from database</div></li>
  <li id="tarheoweh"><div>data from database</div></li>
</ul>
```

The list above is generated dynamically using ajax and jquery, that executes fine without a problem. The problem is that I want to get the ID of a list whenever a user click on any of them and I am currently using the code below which gives me on the ID of the first list element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#names').click(function(){
   var name=$('#names li').attr('id');

   alert(name);
  });
```

The code above executes well but not not the output I want. I need any help, suggestion or criticism. Thanks and I appreciate.

Comment: What exactly you want to do with that id selector

Comment: You're missing a start and end `ul` tag after `#names`.

Comment: This is not valid html...

Comment: I have corrected some of the errors.

Comment: @Akki619 can't I put a div inside a li?

Comment: @user2645613 yes, you can. My bad. Apologizes

Comment: @Akki619 ok, was going to ask for a better way cause am new to web development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<ul class="my-items" id="names">
  <li id="john"><div>data from database</div></li>
  <li id="peter"><div>data from database</div></li>
  <li id="mathhewm"><div>data from database</div></li>
  <li id="philip"><div>data from database</div></li>
  <li id="tarheoweh"><div>data from database</div></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery delegate to attach one listener that catches all clicks on `li` elements under `id="names"`

```
jQuery(function() {
   jQuery(document).on('click', '#names li', function(e) {
      var clickedLi = e.currentTarget.id;
   });
})
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/steveukx/G47bX/) with a working example.

Comment: Thanks, bro... I got it working with your help and thanks for the working example on jsFiddle

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#names li').click(function(){
      var name = this.id;

      alert(name); 
   });
});
```

but you should create valid HTML! `li` nested in `li` is not valid

maybe this is better:

```
<ul id="names">
  <li id="john"><div>data from database</div></li>
  <li id="peter"><div>data from database</div></li>
  <li id="mathhewm"><div>data from database</div></li>
  <li id="philip"><div>data from database</div></li>
  <li id="tarheoweh"><div>data from database</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: `$(this).prop("id")` calls two functions for no real added value. You can simply use `this.id` instead.

Answer (score 1):

That html is not correct, you can place ul under li but cannot place li under li. Apart from that, if ul list is generated dynamically, you cannot use click event. Try "on" event instead.

```
$('#names').on('click', function(){ 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#names').click(function(){
       $('#names li').each(function(){
           alert($(this).attr('id'));
       });
  });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Th2DW/)